# Can't set transparency of QWindow after shown once while opaque

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a window I'm trying to make transparent after being shown once while opaque. However, doesn't go transparent even if I hide and show again. This is what I get:

[image: Black background]

But I want it like this: (transparent against background)

[image: Transparent Background]

If I run `WA_TranslucentBackground` first, *before* `.show()` it creates a nice transparent button as expected.

Here is an example code which shows a floating button when you run it

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class TransparentWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TransparentWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setCentralWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget(self))
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hello World", parent=self))
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.show() # If I move this under '.setAttribute()' it works
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = TransparentWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've tried hiding and reshowing, 'setAutoFillBackground()' and 'WA_NoSystemBackground' attribute, but I cant seem to get it to work. Anybody have any idea how to set the transparency after it has been shown as opaque?

Using versions QtCore: 5.9.6, Pyside2: 5.9.0a1.dev1528389443

Comment: Where did you get the version of QtCore?

Comment: I got the version from printing "PySide2.QtCore.__version__"

Comment: that should be the same version of PySide2, on the other hand the latest version of PySide2 is 5.11.2

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with using this version for now as it i'm version locked to this one...